# Getting Error in asp.net Ajax Website

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webmethod

i have created my site in asp.net AJAX. For AJAX Request i have used jquery and it is calling static WebMethod.

It is working perfectly on my computer but i am getting error when multiple users are using my site.

C# Code

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static string SaveRatingsCollegeReview(string RatingXML)
    {
        UserParam UserParamObj = new UserParam();
        UserParamObj = (UserParam)HttpContext.Current.Session["ReviewDataOfUser"];
        Review ReviewDH = new Review();

        UserParamObj.RatingXML = RatingXML;
        ReviewDH.SaveRatingXML(UserParamObj);

        return "Success";
    }
```

JS Code :

```
function SaveRating() {
    //Finding HTML Controls;
    var CurrentSrNoObj = document.getElementById("cb_SrNo");
    var CategoryIdObj = document.getElementById("cb_CategoryId");
    var titleObj = document.getElementById("txtTitle");
    var WhyObj = document.getElementById("txtWhy");
    var GreatObj = document.getElementById("txtGreat");
    var NotGreatObj = document.getElementById("txtNotGreat");
    var Rating = document.getElementById("currentRating0");

    titleObj.focus();

    var ErrorObj = ValidateForm(titleObj,WhyObj,GreatObj,NotGreatObj,Rating);

    if (ErrorObj.IsValid == true) {
        var parameters = JSON.stringify({ 'CategoryId': CategoryIdObj.value, 'SrNo': CurrentSrNoObj.value, 'Title': titleObj.value, 'Why': WhyObj.value, 'Great': GreatObj.value, 'NotGreat': NotGreatObj.value, 'Rating': Rating.value});
        AjaxRequestUsingPost("../AjaxFunctions.aspx/SaveReview3", parameters, SuccessRedirect); // Wrapper function to make ajax call
    }
    else 
    {
        alert(ErrorObj.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the relevant code?

Comment: Can you please share some of your code and error message to get the clarity.